# Why does python skip my while loop in my primality test when I enter a huge number?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, primality-test

I'm currently trying to make a simple primality test using python to test prime number.

Here is the code I've made for the test:

```
def is_prime(n):      
    if np.mod(n, 2) == 0:          
        return False

    f = 3

    while np.square(f) <= n:       
        if np.mod(n, f) == 0:
            return False
        f += 2

    return True
```

I run the code, and it works fine for small numbers. Then I enter a huge number (for convenience, I chose `2^128`), it returns True. But when I enter  `2^129`, `2^130`, `2^131`, `2^132` (and so on), it *always returns True*. I believe my loop has been skipped. To verify this, I modified the code like below:

```
while np.square(f) <= n:       
    if np.mod(n, f) == 0:
        print(f)    #Added line
        return False
    f += 2

print(f)     #Added line
```

I test this again for some small numbers, and it'll print the correct value of f. But for arbitrarily large numbers (higher than '2^50', maybe), it'll only print 3 (the initial value of f). So I am sure that this while loop has been skipped.

Is there a way to fix this?

**P/S:**

- I've also made other primality test. But I want to use this test as a verification for the result of those tests (though it'll take longer)
- I also using Numba to speed up my code (`@jit(nopython=True)`). This is why I use a lot of np function, as Numba work efficiency with NumPy

**Edit 1:**

- I have re-test the code without, and it works perfectly fine (even with massive numbers) but it much slower. So I guess there is a problem with Numba when handling a large number

Comment: `2^129` mean `1 << 129`?

Comment: NumPy doesn't handle huge numbers. NumPy is built around machine-native data types, not arbitrary-precision integers.

Comment: Numba cannot accelerate arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

Comment: (Also, calling `np.square` or `np.mod` instead of `**2` or `%` isn't necessary to use NumPy, and won't provide any benefit. The benefits of NumPy come from operating on NumPy arrays. If `a` and `b` are NumPy arrays, `a**2` and `a%b` will automatically perform operations across the whole arrays in efficient C-level loops with minimal per-element overhead. On the other hand, if `a` and `b` are scalars, calling `np.square` or `np.mod` won't provide any efficiency benefit.)

Comment: That's not a NumPy array, and even if it was, you wouldn't get the benefits of NumPy by operating on individual elements like that.

Comment: Numba can deal with individual elements more efficiently, but it still needs to work with native data types to have any benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By the way, do you have any suggestions to make my code work well with Numba? I'd appreciate for that:D

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I noticed that without Numba, NumPy works fine. Even with numbers like `2**86243`, NumPy can handle it and calculated quickly. The problem only occurs, if I use Numba.

Comment: NumPy is falling back on Python object operations there. It's not actually accelerating anything.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, so I guess the problem is that Numba can't handle huge numbers.